# The constructors Integer(int), Double(double), Long(long) and so on are deprecated

Tags: java

While working, I got the warning

```
The constructor Integer(int) is deprecated
```

and I couldn't find an alternative constructor/solution online. How can I resolve this issue ?

**UPDATE**

I will get a similar warning with constructors for other primitive wrapper types; e.g.

```
The constructor Boolean(boolean) is deprecated
The constructor Byte(byte) is deprecated
The constructor Short(short) is deprecated
The constructor Character(char) is deprecated
The constructor Long(long) is deprecated
The constructor Float(float) is deprecated
The constructor Double(double) is deprecated
```

Does the same solution apply to these classes as for `Integer`?

Comment: Because there's a cache of Integer from -128 to 127. Using `valueOf` for that range will return those instance instead of create a new instance again and again.

Comment: @AlexH it seems kind of a waste when Double.valueOf(8.5) == Double.valueOf(8.5) is actually still false. Its not as if we are struggling for memory in the 21st century.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You can use

```
Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(i);
```

From [the javadoc of the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-int-):

> Deprecated. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The
>   static factory valueOf(int) is generally a better choice, as it is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.
>   Constructs a newly allocated Integer object that represents the
>   specified int value.

The main difference is that you won't always get a new instance with `valueOf` as small `Integer` instances are cached.

---

All of the primitive wrapper types (`Boolean`, `Byte`, `Char`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float` and `Double`) have adopted the same pattern.  In general, replace:

```
    new <WrapperType>(<primitiveType>)
```

with

```
    <WrapperType>.valueOf(<primitiveType>)
```

(Note that the caching behavior mentioned above differs with the type and the Java platform, but the Java 9+ deprecation applies notwithstanding these differences.)

Comment: Not to mention that because of autoboxing, you don't really need to even use `valueOf(int)`.

Comment: @Kayaman Not always: For example you might have those two methods defined: `someMethod(Integer i)` and `someMethod(int i)` (yes I'm aware this isn't especially a best practice)

Comment: Well that's a synthetic example, since only a psychopath would overload `int` and `Integer`, and have the methods have different logic. There might be some special cases where you would explicitly use `valueOf(int)`, but I'm having a hard time coming up with something that would be "natural".

Comment: @Kayaman I suspect that a well designed code makes that usage fairly rarely necessary. But I know there are many psychopaths around us...

Comment: @Kayaman Psychopaths writing the collections API? :-)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-

Comment: Just a note on deprecated - java.lang.Double​(double) :  java.lang.Double​(double)  It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory Double.valueOf(double) is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance. - Same basic problem with similar answer. - See list of Java-11 Deprecated items here https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Interesting - and thanks for the explanation. After thinking about this for a while, I think this was an improvement, as it is a simplifcation ultimately.

Comment: Why on earth did they feel the need to affect us, when all they had to to was rewrite the contents of their constructor and not impact the humble programmer.

Comment: @AndrewS Because they cannot rewrite the constructor in a way that it will use caching :)

Comment: @soc @Kayman The `List.remove` methods are *not* a product of "Psychopaths", that merely has historic reasons. While collections API is from Java 1.2, autoboxing was introduced much later, so there wasn't an ambiguity at that time. While they could have choosen distinct names for the methods, they couldn't have predicted autoboxing.

Comment: @DorianGray Could you provide a little more detail why not? For example, why not just call the valueOf function from the constructor?

Comment: Because a constructor will always allocate space for a new object. That is how it works in the Java language.

Comment: The `new` keyword is indeed unfortunate that it controls the instance construction from outside. Like many bad things in Java it was copied from C++ :D `new` can be contrasted with Python where new instances are *always* constructed in a factory - and, @AndrewS, your way *would* work there (and indeed does work). The Pythonic way would have been to have syntax `Integer integer = Integer(i);` and let the class `Integer` to decide whether it would return a new instance or recycle some old or altogether different in the factory.

Comment: Why did the constructors just get re-written rather then putting the change on the programmers?

Comment: @AndrewS Constructors have a clear contract: they build a new instance. In order to be able to reuse instances, another function had to be defined. The deprecation here is kind of a "soft" deprecation: the constructor can still be used and is unlikely to go away but it's deprecated so that people use the factory function instead unless they really want a new instance (which is rare).

Comment: Don't forget that Java didn't always have autoboxing ([it was added in Java 1.5 (aka Java 5)](https://www.journaldev.com/1005/autoboxing-java). So it was perfectly reasonable to have `FrobTheGrobber(long value)` and `FrobTheGrobber(Long value)`. You just have to take care when you start to blindly follow the warnings, and code magic, and remove the manual boxing - because your *"improvement"* can end up breaking perfectly functional 22 year old code. (Especially since the invention of auto-boxing didn't also throw a warning about two methods with signatures that only differ in Boxed or not).