# How to remove an especific object from an ArrayList of Integers in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

> This is not a duplicate! It's true that the literal question has been
>   asked before, but neither the question had same intention (focus on
>   int and Integer and deprecation) nor the answers answered what I was
>   looking for.

I looked a lot through StackOverflow. I seen the same questions and answers over and over again, but they don't address the real problem.

There is Java. Java has `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` has the method `remove()`.
The JDK9 Documentation says it can take the index as a parameter or the object itself that you want to be removed.
The following code does not work though.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tea {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        myList.add(69);

        myList.remove( ( (int) 69 ) );

        System.out.println(myList);

    }
}
```

It compiles, but it does not run and so it gives the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 69 out-of-bounds for length 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:517)
    at Tea.main(Tea.java:10)
```

The JVM is obviously taking the argument as the index and not the object.
Here's the suggested solution found on the other websites:

```
myList.remove(new Integer(69));
```

It doesn't even compile into bytecode:

```
Note: Tea.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Compiling with:

```
$javac Tea.java -Xlint:deprecation
```

Gives us:

```
warning: [deprecation] Integer(int) in Integer has been deprecated
    myList.remove(new Integer(69));
```

I looked in the deprecated list on the documentation. Couldn't find it.
Looked the method's documentation to have it explained to me. No explanation.

All I want to do is use the parameter as an object and not the index and get my return as a boolean (documentation says so) if it was in the `ArrayList` and has been removed.

Is there a way to do this? Or is it deprecated and my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>F</kbd> search on the deprecated methods not enough?

Comment: Google search tends to work better than Ctrl + F search - [The constructor Integer(int) is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47095474)

Comment: I also did that. That was the first resource, but the documentation is complete. arraylist.remove() is not deprecated, the (new Integer (69)) is though.

Comment: If your question is about the deprecation of `new Integer(int)`, than please remove all references to `ArrayList.remove` since they are irrelevant. Also: please do not randomly add tags to the question. [tag:linux], [tag:android] and [tag:performance] have nothing to do with anything related to your question.

Comment: Note: a comment on the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger) (and [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095474/the-constructor-integerint-is-deprecated)) points out `Integer.valueOf(n)` as an alternative to `new Integer(n)`, and the second-from-top answer mentions `(Integer) n`, either of which should work for you, whether your question is about removing an `Integer` from an `ArrayList<Integer>` or about general alternatives to `new Integer(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

use `Integer` cast rather than `int`:

```
boolean success = myList.remove((Integer) 69);
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!!